Why can't I CD into directory in Windows 10?
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I go into Command Prompt (either elvated or not), and type: cd H: I am met with the following output:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4894]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USERNAME>cd H:
H:\

C:\Users\USERNAME>dir

As you can see the directory does not change. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried this method of 'drag-and-drop method by typing cd, dragging the folder into the window, and pressing Enter.' This didn't do anything (nothing changed in the CMD window).

so I was never clear on the why of this, but it goes all the way back to early DOS (I want to say at least DOS 3).  basically the cd command is not for changing drives, because each drive has its own "current directory" so you needed to use two commands to achieve what you want to do. more talk of that here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563

You need to just enter the drive
C:\Users\USERNAME> H:
C:\Users\USERNAME> cd \

cd H: will set the current directory for the H: drive but it will NOT change you to that directory.  It will leave you where you were.  You need to just use the drive letter as the command to switch to the current directory for that drive.
As noted below you can also use to change to the drive immediately
cd /d H:

Or use the /d argument: C:\Users\USERNAME>cd /d H: changes dire3ctory in one step, too.

Ah, of course.  Thanks, I always forget about that after so many years on autopilot.

No, no, don't trust Autopilot, yet. ;-)

Hahaha, for sure

You can try Slick Cmd to automatically add the /d switch when using cd to change directories across different drives.
